# Unable to run spark master in dse 4.5 and slaves file is missing

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.0

I have 5 node cluster in DSE 4.5 is running and up. out of 5 nodes 1 node is hadoop_enabled and spark_enabled but spark master is not running.

```
 ERROR [Thread-709] 2014-07-02 11:35:48,519 ExternalLogger.java (line 73) SparkMaster: Exception in thread "main" org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /54.xxx.xxx.xxx:7077
```

Anyone have any idea on this?? I have also tried to export SPARK_LOCAL_IP but this is also not working

DSE documentation wrongly mentioned that spark-env.sh configuration file is resources/spark/conf/spark-env.sh. actual path of configuration dir is /etc/dse/spark.

Slaves is also missing from conf dir and RUN files is also missing from bin dir.
I'm getting below error
$ DSE SPARK

```
 Welcome to
   ____              __
  / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
 _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
/___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 0.9.1
   /_/

 Using Scala version 2.10.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_51)
 Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
 Type :help for more information.
 Creating SparkContext...
 14/07/03 11:37:41 ERROR Remoting: Remoting error: [Startup failed] [
 akka.remote.RemoteTransportException: Startup failed
    at akka.remote.Remoting.akka$remote$Remoting$$notifyError(Remoting.scala:129)
    at akka.remote.Remoting.start(Remoting.scala:194)
    at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.init(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:184)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start$lzycompute(ActorSystem.scala:579)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start(ActorSystem.scala:577)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.start(ActorSystem.scala:588)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:111)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.createActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:139)
    at shark.SharkContext.<init>(SharkContext.scala:42)
    at shark.SharkEnv$.initWithSharkContext(SharkEnv.scala:90)
    at com.datastax.bdp.spark.SparkILoop.createSparkContext(SparkILoop.scala:41)
    at $line3.$read$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:10)
    at $line3.$read$$iwC.<init>(<console>:32)
    at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:34)
    at $line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:38)
    at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at $line3.$eval$.<init>(<console>:7)
    at $line3.$eval$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:772)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1040)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:609)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:640)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:604)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:793)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:838)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:750)
    at com.datastax.bdp.spark.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSparkContext$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:66)
    at com.datastax.bdp.spark.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSparkContext$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.beQuietDuring(SparkIMain.scala:258)
    at com.datastax.bdp.spark.SparkILoop.initializeSparkContext(SparkILoop.scala:65)
    at com.datastax.bdp.spark.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$5.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:908)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.runThunks(SparkILoopInit.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runThunks(SparkILoop.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.postInitialization(SparkILoopInit.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.postInitialization(SparkILoop.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:925)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:881)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:881)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:881)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:973)
    at com.datastax.bdp.spark.SparkReplMain$.main(SparkReplMain.scala:22)
    at com.datastax.bdp.spark.SparkReplMain.main(SparkReplMain.scala)
 Caused by: org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /54.xx.xx.xx:0
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:272)
    at akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$listen$1.apply(NettyTransport.scala:391)
    at akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$listen$1.apply(NettyTransport.scala:388)
    at scala.util.Success$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Try.scala:206)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:206)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:67)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:82)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:58)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:42)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
 Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss$RegisterTask.run(NioServerBoss.java:193)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.processTaskQueue(AbstractNioSelector.java:366)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:290)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss.run(NioServerBoss.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
]
org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /54.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:0
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:272)
    at    akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$listen$1.apply(NettyTransport.scala:391)
    at   akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$listen$1.apply(NettyTransport.scala:388)
    at scala.util.Success$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Try.scala:206)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:206)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:67)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:82)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:58)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:42)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss$RegisterTask.run(NioServerBoss.java:193)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.processTaskQueue(AbstractNioSelector.java:366)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:290)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss.run(NioServerBoss.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>
```

spark-env.sh

```
   export SPARK_HOME="/usr/share/dse/spark"
   export SPARK_MASTER_IP=54.xx.xx.xx (public IP)
   export SPARK_MASTER_PORT=7077
   export SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=7080
   export SPARK_WORKER_WEBUI_PORT=7081
   export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY="4g"
   export SPARK_MEM="2g"
   export SPARK_REPL_MEM="2g"
   export SPARK_CONF_DIR="/etc/dse/spark"
   export SPARK_TMP_DIR="$SPARK_HOME/tmp"
   export SPARK_LOG_DIR="$SPARK_HOME/logs"
   export SPARK_LOCAL_IP=54.xx.xx.xx (public IP)
   export SPARK_COMMON_OPTS="$SPARK_COMMON_OPTS -Dspark.kryoserializer.buffer.mb=10 "
   export SPARK_MASTER_OPTS=" -Dspark.deploy.defaultCores=1 -    Dspark.local.dir=$SPARK_TMP_DIR/master -Dlog4j.configuration=file://$SPARK_CONF_DIR/log4j- server.properties -Dspark.log.file=$SPARK_LOG_DIR/master.log "
   export SPARK_WORKER_OPTS=" -Dspark.local.dir=$SPARK_TMP_DIR/worker -Dlog4j.configuration=file://$SPARK_CONF_DIR/log4j-server.properties -Dspark.log.file=$SPARK_LOG_DIR/worker.log "
   export SPARK_EXECUTOR_OPTS=" -Djava.io.tmpdir=$SPARK_TMP_DIR/executor -Dlog4j.configuration=file://$SPARK_CONF_DIR/log4j-executor.properties "
   export SPARK_REPL_OPTS=" -Djava.io.tmpdir=$SPARK_TMP_DIR/repl/$USER "
   export SPARK_APP_OPTS=" -Djava.io.tmpdir=$SPARK_TMP_DIR/app/$USER "

   # Directory to run applications in, which will include both logs and scratch space  (default: SPARK_HOME/work).
   export SPARK_WORKER_DIR="$SPARK_HOME/work"
```

Comment: Just to make it clear: you have 4 nodes which run pure Cassandra and one node which is mixed Hadoop/Spark?

Comment: In 5 node cluster 2 are cassandra , 2 are solr and one is on hadoop/spark.

Comment: Is the interface, mentioned in the exception, the one which you want it to bind to? Maybe there is more detailed information in master.log - can you check it?

Comment: Spark Master uses broadcast address as an interface which it binds to. If you want to change it, you may consider changing listen_address parameter in cassandra.yaml.

Comment: my cluster is on EC2, that's y I left Listen_address blank. When I'm giving broadcast address then I'm getting error of Invalid yaml due to broadcast message. But The IP address 54.xx.xx.xx i mentioned is correct ip of my node. but still it is not able to bind. I have also checked master.log. same error message. SparkMaster: Remoting error: [Startup failed] .SparkMaster: Exception in thread "main" org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /54.xx.xx.xx:7077

Comment: The location you noted $DSE_HOME/resources/spark/conf/spark-env.sh is the install location for a tarball install, you have a package install which is why you don't see the files in that location.

[Package file locations][1]

I would guess that your issue is that the firewall (either Ec2 or local node) on your group of nodes is keeping the address from being bound. Do you see any additional errors in /var/log/cassandra/system.log?

  [1]: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/reference/refDsePackageLoc.html

Comment: Yes I'm able to find the package location which is /etc/dse/spark/spark-env.sh. All necessary port are open in security group. on /var/log/cassandra/syatem log and Master.log have same error, which i posted in my question.

Comment: In this log message: org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /54.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:0 - did you masked the real port with 0 or it was 0?

Comment: i didn't mask port with 0. Actually, DSE SPARK give this err :
org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /54.xx.xx.xx:0
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
 and 
System log and Master log err msg :
Startup failed
Caused by: org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /54.xx.xx.xx:7077
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address

Comment: It is quite strange then. Is it possible for you to check if the same problem exists when you run Spark Master manually? Just download pure Spark and try to run `spark-master.sh`.

Comment: I'have already tried to manually installed and configure that before doing with DSE, i did not face any problem in executing spark shell. May this is dse spark integration issue or may i'm missing something.

Comment: I have never seen this error in DSE. Which Java version do you use?

Comment: I've looked into the code and the only thing I can tell is that this is a security related problem. DSE and its server components are run as CASSANDRA user - can you check if CASSANDRA user has enough privileges to open ports?

Comment: Thanks Jack, Did you tried to SPARK Shell in DSE 4.5? If Yes, then please share the configuration step, may be I'm missing something.

Comment: I don't use any special settings. I just run it and it works. Why don't you create a support ticket?

Comment: Can please guide me where and how to do that ?

Comment: Sorry, for late response - do you use DSE for testing or you bought it for production? Also, if you still have this problem - can you check the most obvious thing - is there any other process which is running on 7077 port? Also - have you tried to run Spark Master by your own before? If so, did you stopped it properly?

Comment: Thanks for response Jack. Right now I in development phase after that we will take this to production. IS this can be case that, I'm trying to make only one node to SPARK and For SPARK might require to configure on two nodes , one for Master and other for worker.And explicitly set make one node a master node. ?? I'm sure I'm missing something in configuration only but not able to find where.

Comment: Basically, when you start DSE in Spark mode (I mean `dse cassandra -k` if you use tarball installation), it automatically starts two processes - Spark Master and Spark Worker. They both works on the same machine. If you start other nodes in Spark mode, in the same datacenter, they will run only Spark Worker. There should be no conflicts. You probably shouldn't change anything besides listen addresses of Cassandra (in `cassandra.yaml` file).

Comment: In cassandra.yaml , listen address is 0.0.0.0 . Do i need to change it ??

Comment: It is a good practice to change it to the actual interface you want to listen on. However, this seems to not be the case in this particular situation. Please look here http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/install/installAMISecurityGroup.html and make sure you have configured the port 7077 properly.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the configured Akka Remote host:port for your SparkConf and any related akka configuration in a reference.conf file. This seems like an akka startup conflict related to akka remote and a host:port it expects to use but is already taken: i.e. the ChannelException. Something else is already using 54.xx.xx.xx:0 when Spark's akka ActorSystem starts up.

Comment: Where i can find reference.conf file? As you said this can be port conflict, that means that's why i'm getting error fail to bind 54.xx.xx.xx:7077? but I did netstat -anp | grep 7077 and port 7077 is not used anywhere. Is there any other way I can check weather 54.xx.xx.xx:7077 or 54.xx.xx.xx:0 port assigned to any other process.

Comment: The akka actor system is created internally by spark, using the host port from:
"spark.driver.host"
"spark.driver.port"
In Akka atleast, port 0 is passed to Netty which uses 0 as a signal to use a dynamic port number. Do you already have a node running ?

Comment: Try adding SPARK_LOCAL_IP=master in both slaves or check your your spark-env.sh

Comment: Helena, I'm trying to configure standalone spark&hadoop node.please have a look on my spark-env.sh file (updated the question). Is very thing correct or I need to modify something in it ?